# How to remove parent element by clicking on child?

Tags: d3.js

I have a tooltip group (the parent) with a close button (the child) inside of it.

When I click an element to open the tooltip, I run a function to delete any old instances of the tooltip.

The function is this:

```
function removeBubblePopup(){
    d3.selectAll(".popupForBubble").remove();
}
```

This works.

My problem comes from when I try to run the function from the tooltip itself, i.e. when the user clicks on the close button, I want to delete the tooltip.

I've played around with the removeBubblePop() function to make sure it gets correctly called and that the selection is correct, but things just don't delete.

My best guess is that it has something to do with the fact that the command to delete the parent level element comes from within the child and therefore, the child still must exist so that the command can be executed. Wondering if some sort of callback might work, but I don't know how to make that happen.

FYI, I've tried these variations:

```
higherCirc
.on("click", function(){
    removeBubblePopup();
 });
```

AND

```
higherCirc
.on("click", removeBubblePopup)
```

AND

```
higherCirc
.on("click", function(){
    d3.selectAll(".popupForBubble").remove();
 });
```

Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Comment: Try to make a fiddle, then we could do something on it...

Comment: Maybe event bubbling will help... Put the listener on the svg then select back in to delete the tool tips...

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I did make a [fiddle to help illustrate my problem](https://jsfiddle.net/jesspeter/w7f0uduv/20/). Notice how when you click on one circle and then the other, the first tooltip disappears, but if you click the "x" nothing happens.

Cool Blue: Interesting suggestion, but I'm not sure how I'd implement it with my layout.

I also know I could simply work around the problem by using a single element that I just show/hide and move around, but I'm interested to see first if I can resolve the issue with my current method.

Comment: Fixed my issue. It was due to the fact that tooltip was in the same group as the parent nodes, so each click on the "X" was causing the display tooltip function to be called again. Sort of a "doi" moment, but I'm glad to have sorted things out.